# how get all messages when new client subscribe instead last one message (mqtt, retain)

Tags: javascript, mqtt

How get all messages when new client subscribe instead last one message (mqtt, retain)?
I have two applications. I set retain, clean flag and qos: 1. I used same code for both applications.
Example:

- app_1 -> user writes message: hello --> topic1
- app_1 -> user writes message: hello2 --> topic1
- app_2 -> test_user -> connects to topic1

now test_user should be get all messages from user(app_1) [hello and hello2], but I get onlny "hello2"

```
    let client = mqtt.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9001', {
      clientId: "front-client",
      username: "u",
      password: "p",
      clean: false
    });
    client.on('connect', (topic) => {
      client.subscribe(this.topic, {qos: 1}, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('message sent by mqtt')
        }
      });
    });
    this.mqttClient = client;

    //handle incoming messages
    client.on('message', (topic, message, packet) => {
      //
    });

  sendMsgByMqtt(message: string) {
    this.mqttClient.publish(this.topic, message, {retain: true, qos: 1});
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't

MQTT is not a Message Queuing system, it is a Pub/Sub system.
MQTT will only queue messages for existing clients that are currently offline.
There is NO way for a new client to see previous messages published to a topic.

The only exception is if the retained bit is set when the message is published and the broker will only retain the last message published to that topic with the retained bit set. Any new message with that flag set will replace the previous message.

Comment: Are u sure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289471/mosquitto-broker-retain-multiple-messages I added table to post

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I wrote both answers. A NEW client will never get anything other than the last retained message.

Comment: The only way the broker will queue messages, is if that client has already been connected and subscribed to the topic in question at better than QOS0 and when it reconnects it has clean session set to false. For a new client it doesn't matter what the clean session flag is set to as the broker doesn't know to keep messages for that client id.

Comment: HiveMQ has a good page that describes all this:  https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/

Comment: @mmuserdev - You might be better served by using something like Apache Kafka, which does "Event Streaming" and sounds more like what you are looking to do.  https://kafka.apache.org/